# OpenCV - Problems with gpu::convolve

Tags: opencv, gpu

I am doing some 2D Convolutions with different kernel sizes using the gpu library of OpenCV (Version 2.4.3).

If I use the gpu::filter2D function, the convolution works fine. However if I increase my kernel size from 7x7 to 17x17 then gpu::filter2D errors out. I guess gpu::convolve supports convolutons with larger kernel sizes, but I am having some trouble with it.

As per the documentation, for gpu::convolve, I use the GpuMat version of the kernel whereas for gpu:filter2D, I use the Mat version of the kernel. I have my image and kernel set as a CV_32FC1 data type.

Below is a snippet of my code:

```
struct GPU_Buffer {
    GpuMat InputImage_GPU;
    GpuMat BasisPatch_GPU;
    GpuMat OutputImage_GPU;
} gpuBuffer;

Mat ConvOutputImage = Mat::zeros(InputImage.rows, InputImage.cols, CV_32FC1);

gpuBuffer.InputImage_GPU.upload(InputImage);
gpuBuffer.BasisPatch_GPU.upload(basisPatch);

Point anchor(-1,-1);  // Anchor is at Filter center

int borderMode = BORDER_CONSTANT;

// Works for 7x7
gpu::filter2D(gpuBuffer.InputImage_GPU, gpuBuffer.OutputImage_GPU, -1, basisPatch, anchor, borderMode);

// Doesn't work for any size at all
//gpu::convolve(gpuBuffer.InputImage_GPU, gpuBuffer.BasisPatch_GPU, gpuBuffer.OutputImage_GPU, true);   // true => performs correlation

gpuBuffer.OutputImage_GPU.download(ConvOutputImage);
```

Can someone point me towards a possible reason for the anomaly?

Thanks,

Sid

Comment: It will help if you show us the error you are having.